# AWS EMR Spark error with `Failed to load class of driverClassName com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, jdbc, amazon-emr

I'm currently trying to add a process in EMR 6.1.0 that will use Spark to store aggregated data in mysql.
However, when I actually run Spark, I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName com.mysql.jdbc.
```

This error did not occur in EMR 6.0.0.
In the process of updating from EMR 6.0.0 to 6.1.0, I changed the Spark version from 2.4.4 to 3.0.0.
The code itself has not changed significantly, and we know that it is not a network problem.

I've spent a lot of time looking through the AWS documentation and can't seem to find any hints.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Place the MySQL connector jar under $SPARK_HOME/jars folder or pass the the MySQL connector jar path in spark-shell/spark-submit command using --jars flag.

Answer (score 0):

Spark 3.x depends on HikariCP.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0/dev/deps/spark-deps-hadoop-3.2-hive-2.3#L1

Preloaded HikariCP can't load your application classes due to `ClassLoader`.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/HikariCP-2.5.1/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L318

```java
this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(driverClassName)
```

You should add `shade` settings if use [sbt-assemlby](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

```scala
assembly / assemblyShadeRules := {
  Seq("com.zaxxer.hikari").map { packageName =>
    ShadeRule.rename(s"${packageName}.**" -> s"my_app_shade_package.${packageName}.@1").inAll
  }
}
```